# Update all mail in inbox to remove certain text Runtime Error 430 VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, macros

I keep getting this error recently and I have no idea what is missing? it used to work though. Debugger stops at myStr = objItem.htmlbody and gives a runtime error 430 (Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface)

```
Sub UpdateAllMessages()
' Remove the appended url from all effected urls
' Start execution here
Dim olkSto As Outlook.Store
For Each olkSto In Session.Stores
    ProcessFolder olkSto.GetRootFolder()
Next
MsgBox "All hyperlinks are back to their original state.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(olkFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim objItem As Object, olkSub As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objMail As MailItem

Dim myStr As String

'Process each message
For Each objItem In olkFld.Items
    'Only  messages, not receipts or appointment requests, etc.
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        ' Store the HTML Bodyin a variable
        myStr = objItem.htmlbody <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DEBUG STOPS HERE ERROR
        ' Update all URLs
        myStr = Replace(myStr, "https://test.com/apps/verify/?url=", "", , , vbTextCompare)
        ' only if there is a change
        ' Assign back to HTML Body
        If Len(myStr) <> Len(objItem.htmlbody) Then
            objItem.htmlbody = myStr
            ' Save the mail
            objItem.Save
        End If
    End If
Next
Set olkMsg = Nothing
For Each olkSub In olkFld.Folders
    ProcessFolder olkSub
Next
Set olkSub = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your title says "inbox" so why do you search every folder and sub folder within every PST and OST file on your system?

Comment: When I copy your code to an Outlook module on my system, `myStr = objItem.htmlbody <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DEBUG STOPS HERE ERROR` gives an error. When I add a quote to make the tail a comment, I get `myStr = objItem.HTMLBody   '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DEBUG STOPS HERE ERROR`.  That is, `htmlbody` is automatically corrected to `HTMLBody` as expected. How have you managed to get `htmlbody` on your system

Comment: . My guess is that in some obscure folder you have something that looks like a mail item but isn't. Which folder contains the mail item that gives the error?

Comment: Hi Tony, the line "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DEBUG STOPS HERE ERROR" is added by me here to show where the debugger stops. this happens on my outlook at work but not home it works perfectly fine. I actually want it to scan everything not just the inbox. my work outlook is 2013 and home is 2016.

Comment: This makes my guess more likely.  At work you will have folders such as RSS feeds and Journal.  It is some years since I tried but my recollection is that accessing these folders gives strange errors.  What folder are you accessing when the error occurs?

Comment: i dont know what folders im accessing but all folders i have at work are normal just like home. maybe it's the version of outlook that gives the error?

Comment: I am retired but at work I definitely had to avoid accessing some folders that were missing from my home system. When the interpreter stops, type `? olkFld.Name` into the Immediate Window to get the name of the current folder. If that folder is not unique, try `? olkFld.Parent.Name` and `? olkFld.Parent.Parent.Name` and so on until you have a unique name.

Comment: I think it's from the RSS folder. Is there a way to make the code avoid it? or maybe just scan the inbox?

Answer (score 0):

My crude solution to folders I did not like was a simple `Select Case`:

```
Select Case olkFld.Name
  Case "RSS Feeds", "Journal", "Search Folders", "Draft"
    ' Ignore
  Case Else
    ' Process folder that might contain something interesting
    : :
    : :
End Select
```

**Alternative suggestion**

Your code gives no errors on my system so I cannot test this code but it might help. The following switches off the standard error handler for the problem statement.

```
Dim ErrNum As Long
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
myStr = objItem.HTMLBody   '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DEBUG STOPS HERE ERROR
ErrNum = Err.Number
On Error GoTo 0
If ErrNum = 0 Then
  ' Update all URLs
  myStr = Replace(myStr, "https://test.com/apps/verify/?url=", "", , , vbTextCompare)
  ' only if there is a change
  ' Assign back to HTML Body
  If Len(myStr) <> Len(objItem.HTMLBody) Then
      objItem.HTMLBody = myStr
      ' Save the mail
      objItem.Save
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Around `For Each objItem In olkFld.Items` to `Next`.  That is, around the code that processes folders that might contain something interesting.

Comment: alright will test it tomorrow at work. But i just realized i have rss feed at home too so not sure if it was the reason. Will tell you tomorrow. Thanks a lot Tony!

Comment: didnt work :( it stops immediately at the line described in my post not even reaching the end of the code

Comment: user3454329.  What folder is it in when it stops?  What do you know about the item?  From your description `objItem` does not have property `HtmlBody`.  This should not be possible given you have checked `objItem.Class` but clearly it is.

Comment: user3454329. I have added an alternative suggestion to my answer.